# Upload APK not working

Tags: android, apk

I have a problem when I'm publishing my app in play Store, and I'm having a huge problem: it stops at `40%` and I don't know the reason!?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because stackOverflow is not google's customers  support

Comment: sorry but i make research about this topic in google without a result @Selvin and i asked this question because I guess developeur have already have this probleme but thank you anyway

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upload signed APK replace of build APK.

Comment: sorry but its the first time I'm publishing an app, I'm not allowed to put a not signed apk?